# Automatically shutdown when switching to battery

Tags: laptop, power-management, shutdown, battery

I'm recently made my old laptop into a server using Ubuntu Desktop 15.04.
But because my laptop has an almost dead battery I want Ubuntu to save all data that it's on (or at least close the running programs) and safely shut down.
How can I make sure Ubuntu does this when the AC adapter is unplugged?

I might be able to get this done easily by just adjusting the critical battery level to 95-ish. But I don't know what Ubuntu does during shutdown at critical battery level. If this could be the fix then I'd like to know: what does Ubuntu do when shutting down at critical battery level?

Comment: shut down does a normal shutdown and you will need to save your data before

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. If it does just do a normal shutdown I might be able to do it that way. Thanks.

Comment: @charmesal Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @MarkYisri I did not. I eventually got myself a cheap server. But I did find some solutions for you. If you know how to program you van use this [link](https://www.cemetech.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3638). If you can't program, then you could check out [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-obtain-a-laptop-battery-information-and-charging-state-on-linux) and create a  simple bash script
Hope this helps :)
edit: I also just found this suggested post [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/854570/how-to-shutdown-automatically-when-ac-power-is-not-available?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @charmesal Thanks for the info! I am an enthusiast programmer myself so that's fine. (I'm only a student.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package that handles the AC-to-battery transition is `pm-utils`. On a command line, looking at the files in the `pm-utils` package will tell you where to go next:

```
    $ dpkg -L pm-utils
    ...<snip>...
    /usr/share/man/man1/pm-is-supported.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man8/pm-powersave.8.gz
    /usr/share/man/man8/pm-action.8.gz
    ...<snip>...
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/HOWTO.hooks.gz
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/AUTHORS
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README.debugging
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/TODO.Debian
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README.distributions
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/TODO
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/HOWTO.modules
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/copyright
    /usr/share/doc/pm-utils/NEWS.gz
    ...<snip>...
```